# How to run code in firebase without signing user in

Tags: javascript, firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database

Below is the JS code i aim to run :

```
var orderedPlayers = databaseService.s.child("playerweek2").orderByChild("id"); 
    $firebaseArray(orderedPlayers)
            .$loaded(function(loadedPlayers) {
            var normalizedPlayers = loadedPlayers.reduce(function(acc, next) { acc[next.id] = next; return acc; }, {});
            var selectedPlayers = $scope.pick.map(function(num){
                return normalizedPlayers[num];
            });
            $scope.players = selectedPlayers;

                        $scope.sum = function(items, prop){
                        return items.reduce( function(a, b){
                        return a + b[prop];
                        }, 0);
                        };
                        $scope.$watch('players', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.totalPoints = $scope.sum(newValue, 'goals');
    userRef.set($scope.totalPoints);

},true);
```

Is there a way to have this code run at a set time in the week every week without the user being signed in? The issue is the user needs to be signed in for the code to run but I aim to have the code run irrespective of if the user is signed in or not. Is this possible on firebase?

Below is what I tried unsuccessfully:

```
   exports.update = functions.database.ref('/Player')
   .onWrite(event=>{
    var pick=firebase.database().ref("users").child(user.uid).child("selection");
     $firebaseArray(Players)
        .$loaded(function(loadedPlayers) {
        var normalizedPlayers = loadedPlayers.reduce(function(acc, next) 
         { acc[next.id] = next; return acc; }, {});
        var selectedPlayers = $scope.pick.map(function(num){
            return normalizedPlayers[num];
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

[Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) is a part of Firebase that allows you to run code on a server, so the code is independent of any users.

Natively, there isn't a way to "schedule" a function to run (the functions are triggered by database changes, https requests, etc), but this blog post offers a solution: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html

Comment: Thanks, but I tried to block paste the code above within the cloud function and it didnt work (I removed the references to $scope and the service). I take it cloud functions dont take in firebase databse node refs?

Comment: Cloud Functions can use Firebase Admin to modify the database, if that's what you mean. [Here's how you'd initialize Firebase Admin in a Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import_the_required_modules_and_initialize)

Comment: Yes. What I'm aiming for is a change in one database node to trigger a change in another database node. Is that possible?

Comment: It's totally possible, that's one of the main uses of Firebase Cloud Functions. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the question to include the cloud function I tried to run which did not work. Is the problem with my syntax?

Comment: There's a few functions and variables in there that I don't see defined anywhere, but they could be defined somewhere else in the file. In any case, I'm not sure what those variables are, so it's hard to debug. Check the  Functions console for errors, and try to fix those. There's a also a Firebase slack community where you can ask quick questions: https://firebase.community/